# Is it considered Bad Idea to Edit the orginal JQuery File?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have Tabs-Menu controls which rely on jQuery library and the dev-manager insist that i should get the functions that controls are using into a separate java-script file so we don't have to reference/rely on the whole jQuery, so it made me wonder.. is it a bad idea to edit the jQuery files ?

Comment: Just a pointer, but it's called jQuery (no hyphenation).

Comment: It isn't going to be very easy to pull out only the parts of jquery that the tabs menu relies on since it relies on pretty much the entire library.

Comment: what is your dev managers reasoning for this???

Comment: @c0deNinja, u know , load time , performance......etc

Comment: It would **me** wonder, why won't I seek a **new job place**...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is a very bad idea. It would be a nightmare to maintain with all the bug fixes and feature changes the jQuery team would make.

You should write plugins to modify the behavior as you want.

Answer (score 3):

The gzipped production version of jQuery is 31K. Not only is this an unmaintainable idea, but this is a pre-optimization. Any images beyond tiny PNGs or GIFs will likely be as large or larger than the entire jQuery library.

Additionally, this is time that could be spent addressing actual problems. I don't know what sort of userbase you're targeting, but unless every one of your users is on dialup, 31K will take no time at all to download.

Comment: 31KB isn't the only thing to consider, though. Uncompressed, it's a lot of code, and parsing all that code takes a non-trivial period of time. I don't have a link handy but I saw a benchmark showing 300ms parse times for jQuery on some Android phones.

Comment: While I respect that sentiment, your first thought should be, "Can I make this faster without taking a lot of my time," and not trying to splice jQuery into multiple file downloads.

Comment: There are actually existing libraries, you don't have to do it yourself. For example, Ender.js: http://ender.no.de/

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but where does it say that Ender will manage pieces of the jQuery library for you? It looked to me like it's installing and managing other libraries.

Comment: Ender doesn't manage jQuery, but it's built to be pretty easy to convert over to. It wouldn't be a zero-work transition, but it'd be better than manually hacking up jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

> is it a bad idea to edit the jQuery files ?

Yes. If you edit the core jQuery library, you make it much more difficult to use future versions of jQuery, which may include important new features, bug fixes, etc. If you make your changes in plugins, as you should, you can just drop in the new versions of jQuery when they're released.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd say it's a pretty bad idea. You really want the responsibility of maintaining the mess you have left after chopping it out? Are you an expert on the jQuery library? Do you understand all of the side effects? You would be better off rewriting portions of your Tabs-Menu controls without jQuery than trying to chop out bits of jQuery. I presume that the issue is that you don't want the "overhead" of including a relatively large script for a small set of features. This is unfortunately the way of jQuery. Either

- Accept that you have to use jQuery, and make the most of having it referenced
- Rewrite your Tabs-Menu controls without jQuery

any other option is going to be painful. **Insist that your dev-manager reads the answers to the question**.